# NUnit's TestCaseAttribute equivalent in VS Unit Test Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there an NUnit's TestCaseAttribute equivalent **in Visual Studio 2008 unit test framework**?

You know, something like this:

```
[TestCase(1, 1, 1)]
[TestCase(2, 2, 2)]
[TestCase(3, 3, 3)]
public void Test1(int a, int b, int c) 
{ 
    // do stuff depending on the TestCase 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MSTest Have an Equivalent to NUnits TestCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010685/does-mstest-have-an-equivalent-to-nunits-testcase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSTest unfortunately doesn't support parameterized tests in this way. The closest you get is with the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx) attribute, which allows you to specify an **external** data source for the test method.