# NUnit TestCaseAttribute causing AmbiguousMatchException with NUnit VS Adapter

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, azure-devops, vs-unit-testing-framework, parameterized-tests

I wrote a bunch of unit tests that utilized the [TestCaseAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5). These tests run great on my local machine when I use the ReSharper unit test runner. Unfortunately, when I run the tests through Visual Studio with the NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 I get the following output:

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from D:\Projects\Ever\WebApp\Ever.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Ever.UnitTests.dll
Exception System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException, 
   Exception thrown executing tests in 
      D:\Projects\Ever\WebApp\Ever.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Ever.UnitTests.dll
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00.8290488) ==========
```

We use the Visual Studio Online hosted build server for our build, and that **relies on the test adapter to run our NUnit unit tests**. This means I need to figure out a way to make this work with the attribute (much preferred) or I have to work around this limitation.

Do I have to abandon the use of the TestCaseAttribute because MSTest doesn't support parameterized tests<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411321/5190842),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010685/5190842)</sup>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further debuging and testing **I've concluded that the TestCaseAttribute isn't the cause of the issue**. I'm answering my own question instead of deleting<sup>1</sup> in case anyone else falls into the same trap that I did.

The TestCaseAttribute works properly as you can see with the following tests. These tests run perfectly well via the VS Test Adapter and the ReSharper test runner.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleReproAttempt
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(true, false)]
    [TestCase(false, true)]
    public void DoesNotReproduceIssue(bool a, bool b)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(a || b);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("", false, true)]
    [TestCase(null, true, false)]
    public void DoesNotReproduceIssue(string a, bool b, bool c)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(b || c);
        Assert.IsNullOrEmpty(a);
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be present only in tests that have [an overloaded method with at least one of the overloads using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33620614/5190842).

---

1: Editing my question based on this information would turn this into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/301021), and a [chameleon via self answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89306/301021) is discouraged so I dismissed that option as well.