# NUnit multiple TestFixture equivalent for MsTest

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit, mstest

In **NUnit** we can run a test-fixture multiple times with varying parameters simply by specifying multiple `[TestFixture]` attributes, each one causing the class to be instantiated with the specified attribute parameter.

Here is an example:

```
[TestFixture("A")]
[TestFixture("B")]
[TestFixture("C")]
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass(string str)
    {
        ...
```

So the fixture would be instantiated 3 times: with `str="A"`, then `str="B"` and finally `str="C"`.

I'm trying to find the equivalent for the Visual Studio testing tools but the `[TestClass]` attribute can be specified only once.

I've read the doc but found no clue.

I can think of a simple workaround by using inheritance but I'm sure there is a simpler way.

Comment: There is no real equivalent. Closest I think is the Data Driven unit test: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jesse for the information. Really a shame such a basic feature is not yet available. :/ I was used to the best of breed tools (NUnit + TestDriven) but I must make my tests work for the Express version and wanted to demonstrate the integrated tools. Using a DataSource is really heavy and hacky, so I will go with my first idea which is quite elegant but I would have prefered an integrated solution because for me conciseness is better than elegance. :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's "yet" or just "on purpose". Having 3 distinct scenario's might be easier to read when one would have 3 distinct tests (using inheritance you'd have that). But I don't know the exact reasons here.

Comment: I fear the exact reasons are always the same: cost, cost and cost. :) Concerning your edit AFAIK MSTest is obsolete since the new VS integrated tools...

Comment: Not really. The test framework is still called MsTest. But the runner is now encapsulated in the new VS Test Runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real equivalent. Closest I think is the [Data Driven unit test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx).

Comment: MS Test 2 does have a similar feature see this questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010685/does-mstest-have-an-equivalent-to-nunits-testcase