# How can i run multipe MS unit tests with different configurations

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit test initializer:

```
[TestClass]
    public class TestMain
    {
        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Init(TestContext context)
        {
            if (Game.LogIn("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx"))
            {
                //get all entities from db
            }
        }
    }
```

then, run test checks the integrity of the user entities.
How can i run this tests with different parameters (login/password)?

Comment: I'd have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010685/does-mstest-have-an-equivalent-to-nunits-testcase. I've never used MS for testing, only Nunit which has TestCase's for this sort of stuff. Seems harder to implement but hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use different build configurations and settings in app.config for that purpose.