# What is the pendant of NUnit TestCaseAttribute for MS Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, data-driven-tests

What is the pendant of the NUnit TestCaseAttribute for MS Test?

see this sample:

```
[TestCase("Authorization", "Basic", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword", HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[TestCase("Authorization", "bASic", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword", HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[TestCase("WrongAuthorization", "Basic", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[TestCase("Authorization", "WrongBasic", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[TestCase("Authorization", "Basic", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword:anotherpassword", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[TestCase("Authorization", "Basic", "", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[TestCase("test", "", "test@gmail.com:Mypassword", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
public void Authenticate_User(string headerName, string headerValue, string credentials, HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode)
{
    // Arrange
    var encodedEmailPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(headerName, headerValue + " " + encodedEmailPassword);

    // Act
    var response = _client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _server.BaseAddress + "api/authentication")).Result;

    // Assert
    Assert.That(response.StatusCode == expectedStatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Look into `RowTest`, or, even better, look into avoiding MS Test.  Also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTestHacks/

Comment: I looked for RowTest and just found a bunch of very old confusing links!

Comment: @DariuszWoźniak Dude... this link is 6 years old WHY should I care?

Answer (score 0):

The `TestCase` attribute runs the method with the supplied arguments. `Authenticate_User` will be run 7 times with the different arguments.

More info on `NUnit TestCase` at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5

See also [Does MSTest have an equivalent to NUnit's TestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010685/does-mstest-have-an-equivalent-to-nunits-testcase)