# VS2010 Unit testing - rerun the same test with different parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit test that behaves differently depending on parameters passed. Does VS 2010 MS Testing framework have a facility to call the same test with different parameters.
I am looking for something like this:

```
[TestRun(False)]
[TestRun(True)]
[TestMethod]
public void FooTest(bool a)
{
   RunTest(a);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSTest Equivalent for NUnit's Parameterized Tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367033/mstest-equivalent-for-nunits-parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea why Micosoft's decided not to include this feature in their unit testing framework, whenever I search for it I find reference to the *DataSource* attribute that enable loading data from external resource (XML file, data base etc.)

If you do not want to use and external data source then you have two choices:

1. Add RowTest support using MSTest extensability framework - [explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx)
2. I wrote in my blog how to use PostSharp to create the [external data source from the test attributes](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2011/09/enabling-parameterized-tests-in-mstest.html).

If you're already using VS2010 I suggest you go with the first option - there is even a full working code at [Microsoft's code gallery](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/UnitTestExtendSample).

Answer (score 0):

The following page tells how to achieve the same with MSTest data-driven testing capabilities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.dataaccessmethod.aspx