# Is there something similar to NUnit's [Combinatorial] for MS Visual Studio test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

Is there something similar to NUnit's [[Combinatorial]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=combinatorial&r=2.6.2) and [[Sequential]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=sequential&r=2.6.2) for MS Visual Studio Test?

Unfortunately I have to port my tests to VS.

Comment: I don't think there are direct equivalents in MSTest. You could however get some tips on how to write parameterized MSTests in the following SO questions, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2367033/650012) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/347535/650012).

Comment: This is indeed unfortunate...

Comment: If I would have to port NUnit test to MS Visual Studio Test I would just change the employer :) why to go from simple to complicated? :)

Answer (score 0):

Dragged screeching and screaming into MSTests? I hope at least you can express how unhappy you are about the prospect of sub-par tools.

There may be a sliver of hope though since there is a concept called [data-driven tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182519%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which may be able to help you. By using a datasource you can send multiple values to a test, through the use of a [DataSourceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so you could theorically pipe your NUnit tests values into a datasource that would be then be consumed by your MSTest tests

Good luck!