# Alternate ways to MSTest that a string does not contain

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, mstest

I'm writing a curse word censorship system in C# using TDD and as I am fairly new to implementing TDD, I'm wondering if there's an alternative or better way to accomplish the task of ensuring a return string does not contain the curse words and variations on it. Due to this being a public forum, I am replacing the actual curse words in the code with clean words, so assume I am trying to censor the cleaner versions just for this post please:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void process_CensorCode_GivenJerkface_ReturnsStringWithoutJerkface()
        {
            //ACT
            string result = proc.process("Jerkface you Jerkfacing Jerkfacer &*E@*Jerkface391!!", PROCESS_CODE.CENSOR);
            //ASSERT
            Assert.IsFalse(result.Contains("Jerkface"));
        }
```

Obviously, my program also accounts for jerkface, jerKfAcE, jERKfaCe, etc.... and I want to test all of these. Do I need to write out a method for every single one of these variations in MSTest or is there some shortcut way to handle all of these variations in a single test? If you notice any other aspect of my test which could be improved, please also speak up. By the way, I have initialized with the following placed at the top of the TestClass:

```
[TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            //ARRANGE
            proc = new RegExProcessor();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSTest Equivalent for NUnit's Parameterized Tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367033/mstest-equivalent-for-nunits-parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nUnit has TestCase attribute for this scenario. It could be used in the following way:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("Jerkface")]
[TestCase("jerKfAcE")]
//[TestCase("...")]
public void process_CensorCode_GivenJerkface_ReturnsStringWithoutJerkface(string checkedWord)
{
    //ACT
    string result = proc.process("Jerkface you Jerkfacing Jerkfacer &*E@*Jerkface391!!", PROCESS_CODE.CENSOR);
    //ASSERT
    Assert.IsFalse(result.Contains(checkedWord));
}
```

To achieve it with MSTest you should put more efforts because MSTest still does not support test cases in such simple form. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19537323/edit) has details on how to complete it with MSTest.

Comment: It sounds like NUnit is the cleanest approach if it's a possibility, and it is... Have you gotten NUnit's adapter to work reliably with NUnit 3? I've had a few bugs in the past with it where the tests won't all run.

Comment: Support of test cases is one of the reasons why I prefer NUnit over MSTest. As regards adapter - I'm using ReSharper test runner.