# Unit testing various foreach of some inputs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, foreach

Especially for *C# Unit Testing*, how to make a test run for **various inputs** or an input matrix?

I very often have the case of unit tests making a matrix of inputs, but usually it can be reasonably solved by checking a list of inputs.

The simplest case is testing the *addition*:

- 0 + 0 = 0
- 1 + 0 = 1
- 0 + -1 = -1
- 1 + -1 = 0

The same tests would be done for each of those inputs (in this example there are 4 inputs, each associated to some expected output.

The **simple solution** is:

```
object[] inputs = ...
foreach (var input in inputs)
   // Put Assert here
```

The problem with that is that when you run your test it **doesn't tell for which input it failed** unless you include enough details in the message log *manually*.

Another solution is to **unroll the loop** (like below). The stack trace then give which input failed and this allows to run the test for a single input again.

```
TestAddition(0, 0, 0);
TestAddition(1, 0, 1);
TestAddition(0, -1, -1);
TestAddition(1, -1, 0);
```

Last but not least, are solutions like [FitNess](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample) which seem to help such cases but also add a lot of complexity and don't seem to fit well for standard C# development.

**All those solution don't work well with fixtures, because the `[TestInitialize]` is called once for all inputs.**

*What is your solution?*

*Is there some feature I don't know of that helps those cases?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible. The term you are missing is **"Data Driven Tests"** / Parameterized tests. Try with a search engine and you should find quite a few answers for your specific testing framework.

Most of the xUnit testing frameworks have mechanisms to enable this. As Martin has posted, NUnit uses a RowTest/TestCase attribute to pass in parameters to a test.

Comment: See if this helps - tagged: 'shameless blog plug' :) http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/01/nunit-rowtest-extension-running-same.html

Comment: Thanks for those keyworks. With it I found http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sanks/1770/Default.aspx which seem close to what I'm looking (just a bit complex it seems). Searching...

Answer (score 5):

If you're using NUnit, you should have a look at the [TestCase](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.5) attribute.

```
[TestCase(0,0,0)]
[TestCase(1,0,1)]
[TestCase(0,-1,-1)]
[TestCase(1,-1, 0)]
public void AdditionTest(int x, int y, int z)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( z, x+y );
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm using Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework (the built-in unit testing). Never had any issue or reason to change so far.

Comment: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/18/How-to-simulate-RowTest-with-MS-Test.aspx found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347535/how-to-rowtest-with-mstest suggests an approach. Seems a bit heavy to me though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/). You can [try it online](http://www.pexforfun.com/) before deciding it's worth downloading.

Comment: I think this is a bit too advanced for what the OP is asking; Pex if I'm not mistaken is a 'scan and generate unit tests' tool

Comment: It is more advanced. With Pex, the op won't even have to write the data for his test cases.