# To test the function with different values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have test  function:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CreateTest(string input)
{
   string expected = "321"; 
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, input);
}
```

I need to run this test with different data: `CreateTest("321"); CreateTest("123"); CreateTest(null);`
I do not know how to do this before I did something like `[TestCase("123")], [TestCase("321")]`

I need something that:

```
[RowTest]
[Row(1,1,2)]
[Row(2,1,3)]
[Row(1,-1,0)]
public void SumTest(int a1, int a2, int result)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(a1 + a2, result);
}
```

Comment: How will you handle your `expected` result if the input is random ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021881/how-to-run-a-test-method-with-multiple-parameters-in-mstest

Comment: replace the screenshot with copypasted code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [data-driven unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? It doesn't use class attributes, but it should give you the same results.

If you want to achieve **high code coverage**, take a [look at the Pex power tool](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/).

If you want to **model your tests** (**[MBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-based_testing)**), [Spec Explorer is also worth review](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specexplorer/).