# Set Up Test Method with different inputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I want to test the following method in C# for all code paths.

```
public int foo (int x)
{
    if(x == 1)
        return 1;
    if(x==2)
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I've seen this [pex unit testing](http://fernandomachadopirizen.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/unit-tests-generation-with-pex-using-visual-studio-2010-and-c-4-0/) where multiple inputs are tested. How can I create a unit test that accepts multiple inputs?

```
[TestMethod()] //some setup here??
    public void fooTest()
    {
         //some assert
    }
```

I want to avoid creating a test method for each input. I am working with Visual Studio 2010/2012 and .Net 4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a test method with multiple parameters in MSTest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021881/how-to-run-a-test-method-with-multiple-parameters-in-mstest)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [XML, Database, or CSV datasources MS Test](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/18/How-to-simulate-RowTest-with-MS-Test.aspx). Create FooTestData.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rows>
  <Row><Data>1</Data></Row>
  <Row><Data>2</Data></Row>
</Rows>
```

And set it as datasource for your test:

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\FooTestData.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
                   "|DataDirectory|\\FooTestData.xml", "Row",
                    DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void FooTest()
{
    int x = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["Data"]);
    // some assert
}
```

BTW with NUnit framework it's match easier - you can use [TestCase attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.9) to provide test data:

```
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(2)]
public void FooTest(int x)
{
   // some assert
}
```

Comment: Ok in the body i would then have multiple asserts?

Comment: @Gobliins why not? There is no limit for asserts count

Comment: @Gobliins Again, using NUnit you can use the named parameter Result and the tests may be simplified further, dropping the Asserts
`[TestCase(1, Result=1)]`
`[TestCase(2, Result=2)]`

Comment: When the function parameter is a byte array instead of an int, how would the [TestCase(..., Result)] look like?

Comment: @Gobliins `[TestCase(new byte[] { 1, 2 }, Result = 3)]`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky sorry and in the xml for data driven test do ihave to parse the values standing in the xml field? (seems like nunit don´t like my 64bit vs2010 or some assemblies)

Comment: @Gobliins try to reinstall nunit from nuget (on my 64bit system I also had that issue once). And with mstest you should parse values manually - `((string)TestContext.DataRow["Data"]).Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s))`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thx again for the help, now Nunit runs but when using two times [TestCase(new byte[]{1,2], Result = ...)] with result (first test: true, second test: false) then all my testcases await the result from the first testcase, is this a bug?

Comment: @Gobliins I think it could be a bug of test runner you use - try to run tests from NUnit gui or something like testdriven.net. All should work like a charm

Answer (score 8):

If using NUnit [parameterized tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6) is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

In MS Test you can create *data driven* tests that accept different inputs for the same test method.

Here's a blog post on it: http://toddmeinershagen.blogspot.ca/2011/02/creating-data-driven-tests-in-ms-test.html