# How can I write TDD code from the code below?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i =1 ; i<=100;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

        if (i % 3 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("HOON");
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Group");
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("HOON Group");
    }
}
```

I need to write test code using the above code.

There are three features. 
Anyone could you advise me please?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Fizz Buzz's new name?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `homework` or `interview`?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot write Test-Driven Code from existing code, because tests should be written *before* you write implementation.

Simplest way of testing your code is providing `TextWriter` mock to `Console.Out` and verifying generated output.

UPDATE: If you want to use TDD, then you should modify your code to make it testable. Here your `Program` class does to many things - it is responsible both for presentation (output results to console) and business logic (calculating of values). For testing business logic you  should move this functionality to separate class.

Lets start. First test:

```
[Test]
public void ShoulReturnHoonWhenValueDivisibleOnlyBy3()
{
    var hoonGroup = new HoonGroup();
    string result = hoonGroup.Calculate(3);
    Assert.AreEqual("HOON", result);
}
```

It fails to compile, because you don't have `HoonGroup` class. Create class, create method `Calculate`. Make code compilable:

```
public class HoonGroup
{
    public string Calculate(int value)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now your test fails because you are returning empty string. Just hard-code "HOON" to make test pass. Thats OK with TDD.

```
public class HoonGroup
{
    public string Calculate(int value)
    {
        return "HOON";
    }
}
```

Next test:

```
[Test]
public void ShoulReturnGroupWhenValueDivisibleOnlyBy5()
{
    var hoonGroup = new HoonGroup();
    string result = hoonGroup.Calculate(5);
    Assert.AreEqual("Group", result);
}
```

Of course, test fails. Update implementation:

```
public class HoonGroup
{
    public string Calculate(int value)
    {
        return (value == 5) ? "Group" : "HOON";
    }
}
```

Looks stupid. But it implements all requirements of your code. Another test:

```
[Test]
public void ShoulReturnNullWhenValueIsNotDivisibleBy3Or5()
{
    var hoonGroup = new HoonGroup();
    string result = hoonGroup.Calculate(5);
    Assert.IsNull(result);
}
```

No problem - add another condition:

```
public class HoonGroup
{
    public string Calculate(int value)
    {
        if (value == 3)
            return "HOON";

        if (value == 5)
            return "Group";

        return null;
    }
}
```

Tests pass. We need more test cases. It's easy to do with NUnit - just decorate first test with [`TestCase`](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5) attributes ([MSTest also has similar feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021881/how-to-run-a-test-method-with-multiple-parameters-in-mstest)):

```
[TestCase(3)]
[TestCase(6)]
[TestCase(99)]
public void ShoulReturnHoonWhenValueDivisibleOnlyBy3(int value)
{
    var hoonGroup = new HoonGroup();
    string result = hoonGroup.Calculate(value);
    Assert.AreEqual("HOON", result);
}
```

And now its easier to create code which checks if value is divisible by 3 then listing all possible values:

```
public class HoonGroup
{
    public string Calculate(int value)
    {
        if (value % 3 == 0)
            return "HOON";

        if (value == 5)
            return "Group";

        return null;
    }
}
```

I think you get the point and rithm of TDD. Create more test cases for values divisible by 5 and write test for values divisible both by 3 and 5.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, If I assume that I know what should I write in here and I want to write test first, can you add simple example for the above logic please?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code to make it testable.

BTW, it looks wrong, so I would write it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i =1 ; i<=100;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

        var name = GetName(i);
        if (name != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}

internal static string GetName(int i)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            return "HOON Group";
        }
        else
        {            
            return "HOON";
        }
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        return "Group";
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the GetName function is testable.

A test might look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Hoon Group", Program.GetName(15));
    Assert.AreEqual("Hoon", Program.GetName(3));
    Assert.AreEqual("Group", Program.GetName(5));

    // test other values here
}
```

This example assumes that you have use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`. If not, make GetName `public`. For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, this is how you could solve FizzBuzz (which is essentially the same problem) using TDD.

http://chilliandrew.blogspot.com/2013/12/tdd-so-whats-this-test-first-thing.html