# How to pass parameter values from test case in TFS to test method in unit test method using MTM?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, automated-tests, mtm

I would like to pass parameter values from test cases which are present in Team Foundation Server. I do the automation with the help of Microsoft Test Manager.

Below is example test method created using Unit Test Project.

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]

        public void TestMethod1(int a, int b, int expectedResult)
        {

            var sut = new Class1();

            var result = sut.Add(a,b);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);

        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to build this, I get the below error:

> UTA007: Method TestMethod1 defined in class UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1 does not have correct signature. Test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute must be non-static, public, does not return a value and should not take any parameter. for example: public void Test.Class1.Test().  Additionally, return-type must be Task if you are running async unit tests. Example: public async Task Test.Class1.Test2().

How to achieve parameter passing in this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a test method with multiple parameters in MSTest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021881/how-to-run-a-test-method-with-multiple-parameters-in-mstest)

Comment: I would suggest you use `TestContext` instead? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2006/01/09/using-testcontext-in-unit-tests/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read parameter values from a TestCase in TFS, you could use Data-Driven unit testing:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
public DataRow DataRow { get; set; }

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://serverName:8080/tfs/MyCollection;teamProjectName", "541", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
            string parameter1 = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString(); // read parameter by column index
            string parameter2 = TestContext.DataRow[1].ToString(); 

            var sut = new Class1();

            var result = sut.Add(a, b);

            Assert.AreEqual(parameter1, result);
}
```

Note: 541 is the TestCase id.

Comment: I have setup my TFS online. So is this path correct? [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://abc.visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject;unittestproject", "15", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] I tried this but getting error - The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data.

Comment: I myself found the answer. This works fine .[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.Tes‌​tCase", "https://abc.visualstudio.com;MyFirstProject, "15", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

Comment: How to pass XML file (which will have test data)  as test parameter for each test case in TFS?Something like this [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "https://abc.visualstudio.com;MyFirstProject", "TestData.xml", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your requirement. Could you please post a new question and give your request a detail description.

Comment: Sure. I will do and update here once post it. So that you can have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827835/how-to-read-xml-attachment-from-tfs-test-case-to-test-method.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is quite old, but recently I had to migrate a couple of tests to the
newer library versions and I have found out that *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase*
doesn't work in *MSTestV2* , apart from that *TestContext* doesn't have *DataRow* anymore in .net core.
So here is an approach that will work for newer versions of *MSTest* and dotnet.

Couple of things need to be done:

- Instead of *DataSource* attribute will use new *[ITestDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.itestdatasource?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)*
  interface and we'll implement it as data source attribute for team foundation server. This interface will inject parameters from TDS workitem to the test itself.
- We'll use *[TeamFoundationServerClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/19.219.0-preview)* for interaction
  with TFS

ITestDataSource implementation, it actually queries TFS before test execution and passes parameters from TFS work item to the test as arguments (checkout *GetData* method):

```cs
public class TfsDataSourceAttribute : System.Attribute, ITestDataSource
{
    private readonly int _workItemId;

    public TfsDataSourceAttribute(int workItemId)
    {
        _workItemId = workItemId;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        using (var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://team:8080/tfs/MyCompany-Collection"), new VssCredentials()))
        {
            using (var client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
            {
                WorkItem workItem = null;
                try
                {
                    var task = client.GetWorkItemAsync(_projectName, _workItemId);
                    task.Wait(); // force exception to bubble up here
                    workItem = task.Result;
                }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    // rethrow exception so it will have normal display
                    // in test exploere
                    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
                }

                // this filed in a test case in TFS has all the params
                var dataSource = workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource"];

                // parse this xml and prepare data for test
                var tables = XElement
                    .Parse(dataSource.ToString())
                    .Descendants()
                    .Where(xe => xe.Name.ToString().StartsWith("Table"));

                foreach (var table in tables)
                {
                    // return array with only one dictionary
                    // that will be injected into test decorated with this attribute
                    yield return new object[] { table
                        .Descendants()
                        .ToDictionary(xe => xe.Name.ToString(), xe => xe.Value) };
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Gets the display name corresponding to test data row for displaying in test manager
    public string GetDisplayName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] data)
    {
      if (data != null)
      {
          var testParams = (Dictionary<string, string>)data[0];
          return $"{methodInfo.Name} workitem: '{_workItemId}' - ({string.Join(" ", testParams)})";
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Example usage of the attribute with a test:

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    [TfsDataSource(242141223)]
    public void MyTest(Dictionary<string, string> testParams)
    {
        // testParams has all parameters extracted by TfsDataSource from test item in TFS
    }
```