# How to read xml attachment from TFS test case to Test method?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, tfs, mtm

We have test cases in TFS. I would like to pass test parameters in xml file to each test cases.So for that we have an 'attachment' option in each and every test case in TFS. Now how to read that xml file into our test method and make each test case automated in MTM(Microsoft test manager). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not supported to get parameter values from workitem attachments directly in MTM.

The attachment in TFS test case could be reached using an url: `http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/MyCollection/_apis/wit/attachments/e14b962c-b8bc-4e3e-b4f8-398a89c08522`. The `e14b962c-b8bc-4e3e-b4f8-398a89c08522` is the attachment GUID. But When this below, it does not support to do so.

`[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML","http://v-tinmo-12r2:8080/tfs/MyCollection/_apis/wit/attachments/{attachmentId},"Row",DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]`

Here is an user voice that you could vote about your request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18643267-get-test-parameter-value-from-test-case-attachment

Comment: Can we pass xml as a 'string' in parameter section of testcase in TFS? Any idea? If yes , then how to access it in test method? That xml string will have  inputs and output for the test method to validate.