# DataTestMethod vs TestMethod

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I started to use MSTest 2 `DataRow` attributes to check multiple cases in a single test:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(1, 1, 2)]
[DataRow(1, 2, 3)]
public void AdditionWorks(int op1, int op2, int expectedResult)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, new Sut().Add(op1, op2));
}
```

It works nicely, both in NCrunch and in CI. Only now I noticed that there is special attribute `DataTestMethod` that is supposed to mark such tests instead of `TestMethod`.

Is there a difference? A reason to use one variant in particular?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ShreyasRmsft commented the following on GitHub:

> Hi @cactuaroid DataTestMethod is not needed.
>   Go ahead and use TestMethod with DataRows to data drive your tests.
>   For any more doubts follow the official docs at https://github.com/microsoft/testfx-docs

https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/614

https://github.com/microsoft/testfx-docs/issues/64

So, according to Microsoft, it is preferred to use TestMethod over DataTestMethod.

Answer (score 16):

Both attributes work because the same attributes are defined in the same namespace as the previous version of MSTest. This was done for backward compatibility.

Reference :

[Taking the MSTest Framework forward with “MSTest V2”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/)

[Github: Unit Test Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-mstest/PrimeService.Tests/PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.cs)

Comment: I don't understand the backward compatibility argument: `[DataRow]` is new, so if it didn't work with `[TestMethod]`, nothing would be lost.

Comment: @LukášLánský, the name space is what was backward compatible. the new framework has `TestMethod` in it as well and also the same namespaces from the previous one. That way when you remove the older test framework, all you have to do is add the new `[DataRow]` and everything else will still work. Also `DataTestMethod` is derived from `TestMethod`. Test engines would recognize the data test because of this.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `[DataTestMethod]` is the newer, preferred option, and `[TestMethod]` works too, but just for compatibility (or more precisely to ease migration), providing less clarity? I.e. that this answer provides the opposite advice than the second-voted, accepted answer?