# Inheriting test methods across projects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to have a test class for the VS test framework, that is derived from another test class and inherits all its test methods (so that each appears twice). This was suggested in [a comment on another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22641778/1609722).

When this is done within the same project, it works fine. When done across projects, everything compiles fine but the new tests don't show up.

In this [minimal solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xtRcoR9v5dloTCKUyQ-JoS2EV3HrtKVS/view?usp=sharing), the problem is demonstrated. Two projects, in each we derive from the same base class in the first project. But the new (duplicate) tests only show up for the same-project child class.

I suspect something is optimized away in someway, but don't know what or how top debug this. I tried adding a dummy TestMethod to the second-project test class, just so that something must happen with the class - then only this test method shows, without the derived methods. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I was curious because I never did that. Tested it with two new unit test projects and it works for me. Maybe you can prepare a [mcve] so we can spot where it went sideways?

Comment: Do you use .NET Core or full framework?

Comment: @novigt I provided a link to a minimal example. Is that not sufficient?
FWIW, I use VS2013, .net full framework.

Comment: hm, I tested only with 2017, I don't have older versions available. The minimal solution is probably fine, but many people (including me) don't want or simply cannot download files from unknown sources.

Comment: Tested on 2017 and you're right - it works there. I guess it's just a VS2013 bug then.