# Is it possible to parameterize [TestInitialize]SetUp() in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am new to c# unit testing. I am curious if it is possible to parameterize the SetUp method that is decorated by [TestInitialize]

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp(string path)
    {
        fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
    }
```

For example, before each test, I want to be able to pass a unique path to SetUp. Can this be done? I have consulted this post: [How to run a test method with multiple parameters in MSTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021881/how-to-run-a-test-method-with-multiple-parameters-in-mstest) but it does not quite address the problem I am trying to solve, and if it is even possible. Thanks to all of those who respond in advance!

Comment: No, it isn't possible.  However, you can invoke a common method from multiple tests.  That would enable similar behavior where the path is declared per test.

Comment: Mind posting an example?

Comment: "For example, before each test, I want to be able to pass a unique path to SetUp. " - and where would you parameterize that given taht you start A test - and the setup routine runs in the backround before it WITHOUT UI?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void SetUp(string path)
{
    fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
}
```

This is how I ended up doing it... removed the decorator and called SetUp() explicitly in each test.